# PHP File Upload - Changing file name

Tags: php, database, image, file, upload

First time user, My PHP is currently at a amateur leave. However I am creating a basic website (for a car company) whereby the admin user needs to add a pictures. My current code is

```
'echo "NEW RECORD CREATED" . "<br>";
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   }
} } else { echo "Invalid file"; }}'
```

Comment: Totally unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 4):

You just need to update this part of your code ... it will add a unique ID to the front of the file name.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . uniqid() . "_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Christopher! Thats great thank you. Don't suppose you have any idea with your answer to change it to a date so its easier should there be any issues?